# How to Calculate Dry and Wet Spell in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, iteration, time-series

I have a random time series data with four columns like: year, month, day, precipitation. I want to calculate dry/wet spell for different spell-length. I am looking for a more convenient way to do that while currently doing with some ugly codes like below:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('Data Series.txt', usecols=(1,3))
dry = np.zeros(12)
wet = np.zeros(12)

rows,cols = data.shape #reading number of rows and columns into variables

for i in xrange (0,rows):
    for m in xrange(0,12):
        if data[i,1] == 0 and data[i-1,1] == 0 and data[i-2,1] == 0:
            if data[i,0] == m+1:
                dry[m] += 1.0
        if data[i,1] > 0 and data[i-1,1] > 0 and data[i-2,1] > 0:
            if data[i,0] == m+1:
                wet[m] += 1.0
print '3 Days Dry Spell\n', dry
print '3 Days Wet Spell\n', wet
```

Now, if I want to calculate the 4,5,6 days spells, than "if data[i,1] == 0 and data[i-1,1] == 0....." becomes a huge one. Can anyone please help me so that I may give the spell-length only instead of this long-ugly line?

Comment: Having complex data only in lists of lists is generally a bad idea. This is one such example. Here the interesting data is all in the second item of a big set of lists. This makes it tricky to deal with. I'd either extract the data I want from the start, or maybe put it in objects.

Comment: It seems you are trying to calculate a drought index. Check [http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0477(2002)083%3C1149%3AAROTDI%3E2.3.CO%3B2](this paper) for a comparison of some well known indexes. If you have the time pay special intrest on the palmer index, and how he defines the wet/dry spell periods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try something like this:

```
# first extract precipitation data for later use
precipitation = [data[i][1] for i in xrange(0, rows)]

# then test the range (i, i+m)
all_dry = all([(data==0) for data in precipitation[i:i+m]])
all_wet = not any([(data==0) for data in precipitation[i:i+m]])
# of course you can also use
all_wet = all([(data>0) for data in precipitation[i:i+m]])
```

However please notice this method introduces redundant calculations when testing adjacent days, and thus may be not suitable for processing a large amount of data.

**EDITED:**

Okay this time let us look for a more efficient method.

```
# still extract precipitation data for later use first
precipitation = [data[i][1] for i in xrange(0, rows)]

# let's start our calculations by counting the longest consecutive dry days 
consecutive_dry = [1 if data == 0 else 0 for data in precipitation]
for i in xrange(1, len(consecutive_dry))
    if consecutive_dry[i] == 1:
        consecutive_dry[i] += consecutive_dry[i - 1]

# then you will see, if till day i there're m consecutive dry days, then:
consecutive_dry[i] >= m    # here is the test

# ...and it would be same for wet day testings.
```

This is obviously more efficient then the method above: for testing a total of N days with M consecutive range, the previous one requires O(N * M) operations to calculate and this one requires O(N).

**AGAIN EDITED:**

This is an edited version of your original code. As your code could run, this shall also run on your PC or what.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('Data Series.txt', usecols=(1,3))
dry = np.zeros(12)
wet = np.zeros(12)

rows,cols = data.shape #reading number of rows and columns into variables

# prepare 
precipitation = [data[i][1] for i in xrange(0, rows)]

# collecting data for consecutive dry days
consecutive_dry = [1 if data == 0 else 1 for data in precipitation]
for i in xrange(1, len(consecutive_dry))
    if consecutive_dry[i] == 1:
        consecutive_dry[i] += consecutive_dry[i - 1]

# ...and for wet days
consecutive_wet = [1 if data > 0 else 0 for data in precipitation]
for i in xrange(1, len(consecutive_wet))
    if consecutive_wet[i] == 1:
        consecutive_wet[i] += consecutive_wet[i - 1]

# set your day range here. 
day_range = 3

for i in xrange (0,rows):
    if consecutive_dry[i] >= day_range:
        month_id = data[i,0]
        dry[month_id - 1] += 1
    if consecutive_wet[i] >= day_range:
        month_id = data[i,0]
        wet[month_id - 1] += 1

print '3 Days Dry Spell\n', dry
print '3 Days Wet Spell\n', wet
```

Please try this and let me know if there're any problems.

Comment: Thank you, Starrify. But, still I am not clear how the number of occurrence of 3 consecutive dry days for each month can be calculated?

Comment: @user30337 Both my two samples provides approaches for testing if a single day is end of an m-consecutive occurrence of dry/wet days. So just rewrite the line `if data[i,1] == 0 and data[i-1,1] == 0 and data[i-2,1] == 0:` in your code into my method. :) If you are still not clear how to do it please let me know, I'll try providing some full-functional code like yours.

Comment: Sorry, I could not run with any of these two. Could you please clear it once again? Suppose, I have 2 years of rainfall data. So, there are 61 January days. I want to see how many times there are 3 consecutive dry day has occurred in those January days and so on for other months also. And finally these value will be stored in a (1x12) array.

Comment: I am going to sleep now. Please, try to answer me when you get time. Thank you for your kind help. @Starrify

Comment: It's given an error massage like "IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index"... I have tried several other ways, but cannot. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following way of counting the mean dry period convenient. I am writing the code here as it may be useful for someone else:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as itr

#Import daily rainfall time series#
rain_series = np.loadtxt('daily_rainfall_timeseries.txt')

#separate the group of zero values (dry days) in a list of lists#
d = [list(x[1]) for x in itr.groupby(rain_series, lambda x: x > 0) if not x[0]]

#Count the lengths of different dry spells#
d_len = [len(f) for f in d]

#Calculate the mean dry period#
mean_dry_spell = np.mean(d_len)
```